# When pushing objects to array, how to not push same object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, push

I'm creating new array with objects checked in the checkbox. But when i submit again, there's a error "flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `.$3`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used." I want push only unique objects.

I`m using react

```
handleSubmit(){

    let students = []
    for(let idx in this.state.checked){
        if(this.state.checked[idx] ){
            students.push(this.state.allStudent[idx])
        }
    }
    console.log('students', students)
    this.setState({
        studentList: update(this.state.studentList, {$push: students})
    })

}
```

Comment: Sorry i'm a newbie. Thank you for help!

Comment: you don't need to be sorry for not knowing things.  as for the question, just before u push to state .. do a find and if u find skip the push lik ...  a Array.findIndex((i)=>{ return children.id === currentchild.id}) and u should be good to go

Comment: Consider using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an Array : their `add` method is idempotent for a given parameter

Comment: Change `students.push(this.state.allStudent[idx])` to `!students.includes(this.state.allStudent[idx]) && students.push(this.state.allStudent[idx])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using React, you should be able to safely use the ES6 Set Object, which lets you store unique values of any type. (https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/set).

e.g.

```
handleSubmit(){

let students = []
for(let idx in this.state.checked){
    if(this.state.checked[idx] ){
        students.push(this.state.allStudent[idx])
    }
}

students = [...new Set(students)];

console.log('students', students)
this.setState({
    studentList: update(this.state.studentList, {$push: students})
})
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in React.js, but this seems to be a simple problem(pushing only unique elements to a JS array). Your function modified as follows should work:

```
handleSubmit(){
    let students = [...this.state.studentList];
    for(let idx in this.state.checked){
        if(this.state.checked[idx] && (students.indexOf(this.state.checked[idx]) === -1)){
            students.push(this.state.allStudent[idx])
        }
    }
    console.log('students', students)
    this.setState({
        studentList: update(this.state.studentList, students)
    })
}
```

What we have essentially done here is use the 'indexOf()' method on the 'students' array to check if the current element exists in the array - the indexOf() method returns -1 if an element is not found in an array. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah that's totally what i'm thinking. But it still throws "flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key" error. I don't know why.